# Quotes generating when pasting values into txt fille

Tags: vba, txt

I am using the below code to copy a specific range of data and paste the results into a txt file. However, when pasting additional quotes are being generated on the longer lines that are automatically wrapping to a new line. Is there a way to paste the range into the text file and ensure each cell is on one line only, and there are no additional quotes ?

**Example of current output with line breaks that are not present in excel, data is in one cell that does not wrap:**

"Account number|test account|{""TT"":3,""True"",""Dept"",""SubDept"",""Street""|test1"

**Desired output on one line in txt file:**

Account number|test account|{"TT":3,"True","Dept","SubDept","Street"|test1

```
sub Test() 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim formulasheet As Worksheet
    Dim copysheet As Worksheet
    Dim num As Integer
    Dim valuecolumn As Range, cell As Object
    Dim copycolumn As Range
    Dim i As Range
    
    num = 0
    
    Set formulasheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Upload Template")
    Set copysheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Copy")
    Set valuecolumn = formulasheet.Range("B:B")
    Set copycolumn = formulasheet.Range("A:A")
  
    copysheet.Cells.Clear
    formulasheet.Select
    
    For Each i In valuecolumn
        If i.Value > 0 Then
            i.Offset(0, -1).Copy
            copysheet.Select
            copysheet.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(num, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            num = num + 1
            
        End If
    Next i
   
    
    If copysheet.Range("A1") = "" Then
         
        MsgBox "No transaction amounts, please review."
      
   
        Exit Sub
        
        Else
        
        copysheet.Select
        copysheet.Range("A:A").Copy
    End If

   Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus 
   SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}^v

end sub
```

Comment: Using SendKeys is highly unreliable - why don't you write the text directly into a text file?

Comment: Not sure how to do that! This will be distributed to multiple people so was trying to figure out how to complete without needing to write to the C:/.

Comment: It is interesting that the line breaks cause the extra quotes to be added.  Is the Copy Sheet cleared every time?

Comment: It's rather simple to write a text file with VBA and there are lots of examples on SO and the web. And you won't need an intermediate sheet to collect the data - whenever you find data you want to copy you issue a write statement.

Comment: I cannot understand how the string to be copied looks... Is the one without double double quotes?

Comment: @FaneDuru  the current output is generating quotes at the beginning and end of the copy cell value, as well as duplicating the existing quotes within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use `Transpose` to convert the column values into a 1D array which is then joined and copied to the clipboard.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ClipBoard As Object
    Set ClipBoard = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    
    Dim Result As String
    Result = UploadTemplateFormulaText
    
    If Len(Result) = 0 Then
         
        MsgBox "No transaction amounts, please review."
    Else
        ClipBoard.SetText Result
        ClipBoard.PutInClipboard
        
        Shell "notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
        SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}^v"
    End If

End Sub

Function UploadTemplateFormulaText() As String
    Dim Target As Range
    With wsUploadTemplate
        Set Target = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        If Len(Target.Value) = 0 Then Exit Function
        UploadTemplateFormulaText = Target.Value
    Else
        Dim Data As Variant
        Data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Target.Value)
        UploadTemplateFormulaText = Join(Data, vbNewLine)
    End If
End Function

Function wsUploadTemplate() As Worksheet
    Set wsUploadTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Upload Template")
End Function
```

It is very easy to write to a text file.  I recommend using a FileScriptingObject (PC Only) see: [VBA CreateTextFile](https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-createtextfile/)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. Use your existing code up to copying and then the next way to place the content in a text file:

```
Sub copyColumnToNotepad()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, copyPath As String, i As Long, strText
Set sh = ActiveSheet
lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'create the necessary string to pe placed in the text file
        strText = strText & arr(i, 1) & vbCrLf
   Next i
 copyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TestText.txt" 'the path of the text file to be created
 Open copyPath For Output As #1
      Print #1, strText 'place the string in the text file
 Close #1
 'Open the file in Notepad:
 Shell "Notepad.exe " & copyPath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

`SendKeys` is not a reliable way to copy anything...